# control volume and turn off 3g from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, wifi, volume, 3g

I want to know, is their any posibility to control volume and 3g on an ios device using xcode?
my "The Mind" meditation app need that function to stop distractions from outside.

Comment: No you cannot disable 3G. You can change the audio volume, but not the ringer volume. Here's a friendly reminder to use the search next time as this has been asked many times before.

Comment: sorry for repeating the question.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot disable 3g, cellular data or airplane mode

about volume depends on what controls are you using. i need some details so i can help you